# how to take more than one photo in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have to take 4 continues pictures using the webcamera in QML i can take only one picture after that
I get an error from the QML debugger which states "Camera not ready for capture" how do i get the camera to be in ready state after the first capture this is the code i have tried
even if i set the ready state to true: it does not seem to be working? is there an easy way to get my way around this?

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        ColumnLayout{
            width: parent.width;height: parent.height
            spacing: 15;
            Camera{
                id:cam
                captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
                imageCapture {
                    onImageCaptured: {
                         ready:true
                        console.log(ready)
                    }

            }
            }
            VideoOutput{
                id:vid1
                source: cam
                height:parent.height
                width: 800
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

            }
            Rectangle{
                id:rect1
                width: 100
                height: 30
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.alignment:bottom
                color: "#365688"
                Text {
                    id: text1
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text:"capture"
                    font.pointSize: 10
                }
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill:parent
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log("clicked");
                     for(var i=0;i<=3;i++){
                        cam.start()
                        cam.imageCapture.captureToLocation("C:/Users/vinay/Documents")
                        console.log(cam.cameraStatus)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#captureToLocation-method), - _The `imageCaptured` and `imageSaved` signals will be emitted when the capture is complete_. You should call to the next `captureToLocation` only after these events had fired.

Comment: yes i did go through the document and i used OnImageCaptured handler, the problem is imageCapture.ready should be true in order for the camera to capture an image, when the first image is captured imageCapture.ready is set to false and hence i cannot capture anymore images after the first one

Comment: according to your code I see you did it wrong, in loop. Again, from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-cameracapture.html#imageCaptured-signal): imageCaptured - _This signal is emitted when an image has been captured but not yet saved to the filesystem_ so when it fires the `ready` will be false since the saving still in process.

Comment: GOT IT!!!! Thank you sooo much!! got the code working . :D